# Sequence analysis with multiple sequences

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, sequence-analysis

I would like to recognize different states in a sequence of multiple vectors.
To make it little more clear, here is an example:
I have 2 (or more) vectors in a sequence: head position(HP) and eye pupil position(EP).
Now, I want to find out a focus level of a person based on this data.
I pretend, to have labeled video sequences with 3 example states:

- low focus (change of EP and HP in time)
- medium focus (change in HP in time)
- high focus (no change in time)

I want to train the system to recognize these states in a given data sequence.

1. How to formulate my problem with a scientific vocabulary? (eg. Multivariate Multinomial Sequence Analysis, etc.).
2. What technology should be good for this (eg. MultivariateHMM, etc. ).

Any recommended literature or other source of information is welcome.

Thank You.